# How to search a value and return the row from multiple dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

For example if i have multiple dataframes like df1, df2 and df3. I have a column 'phone_no' in every dataframe. How do i search for a phone_no in every dataframe and return the rows where that dataframe is present?

For example

```
df_all = [df1, df2, df3]

for i in df_all:
    print(i.loc[i['phone_no'] == 9999999999])
```

**The above code is returning empty output. The output must be the row where the phone_no contains that particular phone number. How to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this works by comparing `phone_no` to a string:

```
df_all = [df1, df2, df3]

for i in df_all:
    print(i.loc[i['phone_no'].astype(str) == '9999999999'])
```

Maybe you don't need to convert `phone_no` as `str` if it's already the case. You have to check:

```
>>> print(df1['phone_no'].dtype)
object

# OR

>>> print(df1['phone_no'].dtype)
int64
```

**Update**

```
df_all = [df1, df2, df3]
df_filtered = []

for i in df_all:
    df_filtered.append(i.loc[i['phone_no'].astype(str) == '9999999999'])
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not returning the output in dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean by *not returning the output*?

Comment: The output is not in dataframe format.